# see the systemd boot logs?

Tags: debian, systemd

With recent versions of debian using systemd, it is no longer possible to view the [stdout boot messages with boodlogd](https://wiki.debian.org/bootlogd)

The instructions at [systemd debugging](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/Debugging/) don't say how to do this either.

So how does one see the exact on-screen stdout/stderr log messages from the boot?

Comment: `dmesg -T` may be?

Comment: did you try `man -k systemd` at least?

Answer (score 5):

`journalctl -b` shows all syslog messages since the current boot.

Comment: This doesn't show what was printed on the console during boot like the question is asking though. Eg, all the [OK], [FAILED] etc.

Comment: The output may not match the terminal output, but it will contain all relevant information. However if some startup command do odd things like writing to `/dev/console` directly, the output may be lost. If you need all the output, consider to set up a serial console and capture the serial output (like back in the time when serial printers were popular). Today one would use a console server or a laptop, however.

Answer (score 4):

`journalctl --list-boots` will give you all boots, with 0 being the current boot.

`journalctl --boot=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` (replace xxx... with hash from --list-boots) will then let you view logs of that boot.